# Assign resources to another resource based on same key

Tags: terraform

I have two variables as follows:

```
servers = {
  server1 = {
    name   = "Server1"
    project = "Development"
  },
  server2 = {
    name   = "Server2"
    project = "Staging"
  }
}

projects = {
  project1 = {
    name        = "Project Development"
    environment = "Development"
  },
  project2 = {
    name        = "Project Staging"
    environment = "Staging"
  }
}
```

I'm creating servers and would like to assign the servers to a project resource based on the project/environment link.

```
resource "instance" "server" {
  for_each = var.servers
  name   = each.key
}


resource "project" "project" {
  for_each = var.projects 

  name        = each.value.name
  resources   = values(instance.server)[*].urn
}
```

With the above code, the projects get created successfully and **all** the servers get assigned to the project that gets created last.

I'm looking for a way to loop only through the "development" projects and assign **only** the servers where the project is "development" (same for "staging).

Note: I know I could create a nested variable as follows:

```
projects = {
  project1 = {
    name        = "Project Development"
    environment = "Development"
    servers = {
      server1 = {
        name   = "Server1"
        project = "Development"
      }
    }
  },
  project2 = {
    name        = "Project Staging"
    environment = "Staging"
    servers = {
      server2 = {
        name   = "Server2"
        project = "Staging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then flatten this structure but this is not what I would be looking for now.

### Update 1

I tried the following:

```
resource "project" "project_development" {
  #for_each = var.projects 

  for_each = {
   for key, value in var.projects : key => value
      if value.environment == "Development"
}

  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  purpose     = each.value.purpose
  environment = each.value.environment

  resources = values(instance.server)[*].urn
}

resource "project" "project_staging" {
  #for_each = var.projects 

  for_each = {
   for key, value in var.projects : key => value
      if value.environment == "Staging"
}

  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
  purpose     = each.value.purpose
  environment = each.value.environment

  resources = values(instance.server)[*].urn
}
```

but all resources still end up under 1 project, this is like related to the `values(instance.server)[*].urn` that takes all created intances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following

```
for_each = {
   for key, value in var.projects : key => value
      if value.environment == "Development"
}
```

This way the object to loop through **must** have for environment Development

### Update 1

```
resources = [ for key, value in var.servers : instance.server[key].urn
    if value.project == "Development"
]
```

We could take the urn of the servers by filtering, by applying the aforementioned logic

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion. I updated the original post under the `Update 1` section. This suggestion indeed filters the projects but the resources argument is still filled with all servers. It ends up adding all servers still to 1 project.

Comment: @wiwa1978 I added an update to the answer, feel free to test it and provide feedback

Comment: This works, brilliant. Didn't think of that.